# how do i retry scrapy tasks upon failure

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am relatively new to Scrapy. I am running into situations where some of the pages do not load properly. I want to retry that task again 2 times to ensure it works correctly. Note that I do not get a 404 error but it fails while parsing the result due to some missing element.

It happens only for a few cases out of a hundred and I cannot reproduce it as it passes the next time I retry. (verified by capturing the entire response body)

what would be a good way to handle this?

i tried doing

```py
def parse(self, response):
    try:
        #do something
        yield result
    except:
        yield Request(response.url, callback=self.parse)
```

but I think these are getting filtered and recognized as duplicates by Scrapy. what would be the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: To prevent Scrapy filtering duplicate requests, you can use `yield Request(response.url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)`

Comment: thanks a lot, it helps. is there anyway i can limit the number of iterations to ensure i don't end up retrying for genuine failures.

Comment: it's up to the condition you set for retryin on Exception. you may want to narrow the exceptions you want to retry. You can also keep a count in the request's `meta`, like [`RetryMiddleware` does](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/ebef6d7c6dd8922210db8a4a44f48fe27ee0cd16/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/retry.py#L62)

Comment: thanks a lot! managed to create an exception and retry from the crawler itself. used the meta key to keep a count of num of retries. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You should use the `errback` handler in `scrapy.Request` instead.

Here is the example:
```

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=url,
            dont_filter=True,
            callback=self.apply_filter,
            errback=self.handle_failure)

def handle_failure(self, failure):
    self.log(failure, level=logging.ERROR)
    # try with a new proxy
    self.log('restart from the failed url {}'.format(failure.request.url))
    yield scrapy.Request(
        url=failure.request.url,
        callback=self.parse,
        errback=self.handle_failure)
```

```

Comment: This only applies when a request fails though? The OP was asking how to handle an  exception within `parse`. Their answer addresses their question...

Answer (score 1):

here is how i finally implemented my solution.

```
def parse(self, response):
    meta = response.meta
    retries = meta.get(MISSING_RATINGS_RETRY_COUNT, 0)
    if retries < MAX_RETRIES:
        throw_on_failure = True
    else:
        throw_on_failure = False
    try:
        #do something 
        #use throw_on_failure variable to thorw the exception based on missing data from the response.
        yield result
    except specificException:
        meta[MISSING_RATINGS_RETRY_COUNT] = retries + 1
        yield Request(response.url, callback=self.parse, meta=meta, dont_filter=True)
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot to put quotation mark around `MISSING_RATINGS_RETRY_COUNT`?